# O(1) lookup in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, std

Is there a data structure in C++ with `O(1)` lookup?

A `std::map` has `O(log(n))` lookup time (right?).

I'm looking from something in `std` preferably (so not Boost pls). Also, if there is, how does it work?

EDIT: Ok, I wasn't clear enough I guess. I want to associate values, kind of like in a `map`. So I want something like `std::map<int,string>`, and `find` and `insert` should take `O(1)`.

Comment: It all depends on the data, especially the type and *possible* values of the key : so what kind of data you want to store?

Comment: Something similar to a linked array maybe? It has about O(1). A linked array is a Linked List of Arrays.

Comment: `std::unordered_map<>`. And the reason it's in namespace `std` is because it was in namespace `boost` first.

Comment: There is `std::unordered_map`, which was `std::tr1::unordered_map` before C++11.

Comment: @AMCoder: Well, from the edit, we know only the type of key, but not the possible values of keys.

Comment: @Nawaz: As `std::map` allows arbitrary integer keys, it's probably best to assume that he requires it until he says otherwise.

Comment: @DeadMG: If he needs something like `std::map`, then he needs `std::map`, unless he tells us that `std::map` provides him *more* than what he *actually* needs.

Comment: @Nawaz: Except, as he said, with a better performance requirement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Arrays have O(1) lookup.
Hashtable (std::unordered_map) for c++11 has O(1) lookup. (Amortized, but more or less constant.)

I would also like to mention that tree based data structures like maps come with great advantages and are only log(n) which is more often than not sufficient.

Answer to your edit -> You can literally associate an index of an array to one of the values. Also hash tables are associative but perfect hash (each key maps to exactly 1 value) is really difficult to get.

One more thing worth mentioning: Arrays have great cache performance (due to locality, aka. elements being right next to each other so they can be prefetched to cache by the prefecthing engine). Trees, not so much. With reasonable amount of elements, hash performance can be more critical than asymptotic performance.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that there is an unordered map in TR1. Some compilers like VS2008 and earlier GCCs implement TR1 but not C++11.

Comment: @scarletamaranth the main reason arrays are so performant is because they are next to each other -> system just jumps in memory (end of index + sizeof(type)*index) the way you said it isn't exactly clear as you speak of cache.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth yes, but cache can be misunderstood. I would prefer you explain it a bit more before some guys from web development rain down hate

Comment: @Shingetsu "due to locality, aka. elements being right next to each other so they can be prefetched" should be clear enough ;)

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth I guess, still it would also help in letting people see how prefetching engine works. But I'll stop bothering now, can't make everyone be selectively perfectionist XD

Answer (score 4):

Data structures with *O(1)* lookup (ignoring the size of the key) include:

- arrays
- hash tables

For complex types, balanced trees will be fine at *O(log n)*, or sometimes you can get away with a [patricia trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) at *O(k)*.

For reference:[complexity of search structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_data_structure#Asymptotic_amortized_worst-case_analysis)

Comment: Arrays aren't associative. What hash table is there in `std`?

Comment: @AMCoder: There is `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: hash tables aren't O(1) - there still has to be collision handling checks, and iterating the buckets if there is a collision. Best case is O(1), but isn't always.

Comment: @MarcB: They are amortized O(1).

Comment: *O(1 + k/n)* is close enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

An [array](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) has `O(1)` lookup.

Comment: I think the OP doesn't know the size before hand

Comment: What if the key is non-integral? Simple array wouldn't work then. So it depends on the data-type of key.

Comment: only if you know the position where the data is stored. I.E. looking up position 5 is O(1). Searching if the array contains key depends on how the array is ordered if at all.